# Need a large (20 inch +) touch screen monitor Raspberry Pi 3b+/4b running Debian Buster

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, python-3, raspbian-buster, tkinter

I'm looking for a large (20 inch +) touch screen monitor for Raspberry Pi 3b+/4b running Debian Buster. We tried the ViewSonic TD2230 but the driver support is lacking; Tkinter misses about 35% of the touch events. The official 7" is too small for our purposes, but Tkinter gets all the events from it.

Does anyone know of a similarly priced monitor that has official Linux Support? or where to get the drivers to get the TD2230 working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Planar Helium PCT2235 Touch Screen 22" LED LCD Full HD Resolution Monitor with Helium Stand - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01E06JSI4/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E06JSI4)

Answer - I have not done this, but I expect it should. I use it with a custom linux build on a Raspberry Pi and it worked without any fussing. It uses a standard HID driver.

Comment: Driver support is borked on the model for the Raspberry PI 3/4. Haven't checked recently, but as of about a year ago, it's not stable, and barely usable.